# After OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.2, my screenshots disappear

Tags: macos

Right after I upgraded my iMac to OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.2, my screenshots no longer saves to the desktop.  Using "control + shift + 4", my captured shot just disappears, don't know where it goes.

Answer (score 3):

If the location has been changed, then typing this in Terminal
`defaults read com.apple.screencapture location`
will show you where it's currently set to.

If you haven't changed it, i.e. it's still set to the default Desktop & has never been redirected, it will error with
`The domain/default pair of (/Users/[user]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist`

If it doesn't exist & still doesn't save to Desktop, then try resetting it to there with
`defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo bash -c "opensnoop | grep Screen"` in Terminal and take a screenshot. It will show you where it ends up.

What it does:
It monitors all file operations and filters for entries with "Screen" in their names.

Comment: Default name is ScreenShot, with no space. Would that still work?

Comment: I tested it on en_US.UTF-8 and the files are called "Screen Shot yyyy-mm-dd at hh.mm.ss.png"

Comment: Interesting, UK default is same [inc the date format] but no space

Comment: Edited to fit British accent.

Comment: Nice tweak... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To give a more sophisticated and internationalization safe way of doing it the weird way:

Run this and take one or two screenshots and wait a few seconds. It will output the syscalls done by the screencapture process while renaming the screenshot file. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end it.

```
sudo bash -c "while [ -z \$(pgrep screencapture) ]; do :;  dtruss -n screencapture 2>&1 | grep rename; done"
```

Example output:

```
4737/0xacd92:  rename("/Users/max/Desktop/.Screen Shot 2016-01-12 at 18.49.37.png-vHaw\0", "/Users/max/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-01-12 at 18.49.37.png\0")        = 0 0
4737/0xacd92:  rename("/Users/max/Desktop/.Screen Shot 2016-01-12 at 18.49.37 (2).png-CYss\0", "/Users/max/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-01-12 at 18.49.37 (2).png\0")    = 0 0
```

In the case above, the screenshots got saved to `/Users/max/Desktop/`.